# C# How do I get the GameObject linked to a Transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I have `Tile` objects with an associated `Tile.cs` file. These `Tile` objects have a variable `List<Transform> connections` that links them to other Tile objects.

I want to find the connections of connection (circled in green), here is a picture to be more clear:

> link to picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwg1k.png

I can get the first connection (in red) with that code :

```
foreach(Transform t in connection)
{
    t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
}
```

and then I want the connection of each `t`. I tryed to do `t.gameObject.connection`, `t.connection`, and other stuff that didn't work and I can't figure out how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a tile component that is attached to t:

```
foreach(Transform t in connection)
{
    t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;

    var tConnections = t.GetComponent<Tile>().connection;
    foreach(Transform tt in tConnections)
    {
        tt.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```